# group actions and initial state or configuration of the set being acted on

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

Let's say a group  $G$ acts on a set $S$, a set does not necessarily have an order, so to make sense of the group action I would need to provide the set with some kind of initial *state* or *configuration* right?

for example, a Rubik cube could have any initial *state*, it could be in any position when I pick it up and try to act on it with a group action, so the same action will create different results in my cube depending on its initial *state*.

Why there seems to be a focus on group actions acting on sets but there is no mention anywhere of how the set is arranged before acting on it? is it implied that a set has some natural arrangement even if by definition a set does not need to be ordered or arranged in any particular way?

It would seem that without the initial *state*, any action on a group cant be fully defined, since you dont know what element you are acting on.

Comment: There is no focus on this because there is no need to order a set in order to act on it.

Comment: There is no need to impose any condition on $S$. It just has to be nonempty.

Comment: @GeorgeLaw Technically, you could also act on the empty set, but there is not much point in doing so.

Comment: mhhh let's say I have a set consisting of names, and I want to act on it using the group of integers, particularly using the element "+1" of the integers.
Intuitively I know that I could act on it by moving each name "down" the list of names, and the last name to the first place, however, if there is no initial order, it's not defined how it can be done.

Comment: In that specific example, you want to define the action using an order, but that is a very restrictive setup.

Comment: what about a rubik cube and some movements? or the possible symmetries of a protein or any 2d or 3d structure?it would seem that if you act on a group you will not know what it's going to look like after your action if you dont know how it looks like before you act on it.

Comment: You definitely could first define order on that set of names, but it is not necessary. Group action of $G$ on set $S$ is group homomorphism $\pi\colon G\to \operatorname{Perm}S$, where $\operatorname{Perm} S$ is set of bijections on set $S$ (permutations). Thus, if $S$ is your set of words, to define action of $\mathbb Z$ on $S$, you only need to define how $1$ acts on $S$ (since $\mathbb Z$ is free cyclic). Thus pick any bijection $\sigma$ on $S$ of order $|S|$ and it gives you what you want without order. You can define order on $S$ using this $\sigma$: $a<\sigma a<\sigma(\sigma(a))<\ldots$.

Comment: I don't see why any sort of ordering is necessary for those other examples. For the rubiks cube, one action is "turn the left most one forwards" which certainly doesn't care which configuration you already had.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft the action itself does not care, however you don't know what happened after your action. if the cube can't be observed then what's the point on acting on it?

Comment: @Joaquin Brandan, that is why you have notion of orbit $G.x = \{g.x\mid g\in G\}$. You can think of some particular $x$ as initial state and observe $G.x$.

Comment: thanks, I will look into that, I haven't quite reached orbits yet!.

Comment: Let's say we have an action of $G$ on $S$. For $g∈G$, you have a permutation on $S$. So if you have a configuration $x∈S$, you apply that permutation to $x$ to know the configuration after the action of $g$ if the configuration before was $x$.

Comment: (For an action on the empty set, I don't see why we would not allow that, it makes the things complex for nothing and I guess there will be special cases everywhere.)

Comment: Perhaps it would be clearer if the Rubik cube example was made mathematical. Let $S$ be the set of all possible configurations of the cube and let $G$ be the group generated by all possible "moves" you can do on the cube. Now for $g$ in $G$ and $s$ in $S$ the action of $g$ on $s$ is the configuration $gs$ of the cube after doing the sequence of moves corresponding to $g$ to the cube starting in configuration $s$.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how much this might help, but I gave it my best! I don't usually write this long, so this probably doesn't look good.. It can be made shorter but I am too lazy to revise it.

The standard definition of a group action is what follows.

> An action of a group $G$ on a set $S$ is a function $\star : G \times S \to S$ with the properties:
>
> - $1 \star x = x$ for every $x \in S$.
> - $(g_1g_2)\star x = g_1 \star (g_2 \star x)$ for every $g_1,g_2 \in G$ and every $x \in S$.

"Action" is not a physical-continuous-kinda thing (it wouldn't be a mathematical concept then). You simply have a set $S$, a group $G$, and a mapping which assigns to each pair $(g,s) \in G \times S$ an elements in $S$, with special properties.

It's best to think of a group action as follows (equivalently to the definition above). You have a group $G$ and a set $S$, and a function $f: G\times S \to S$. Given $g \in G$, consider the function $b_g(s) = g\star s$. This function is one-one (multiply both sides by $g^{-1}$), and onto: if $s' \in S$, we know $g^{-1} \star s' \in S$, and $b_g(g^{-1} s') = g\star (g^{-1} \star s') = (gg^{-1})\star s' = 1 \star s' = s'$. Hence $b_g$ is a bijective map from $S$ to $S$, i.e. an element of $\text{Sym}(S)$. Now define $\eta: G \to \text{Sym} (S)$ by $\eta(g) = b_g$. This map is a homomorphism as you can check. It's called the homomorphism associated to the action. It can be shown also that any homomorphism from $G$ to $\text{Sym}(S)$ gives rise to a group action (in the obvious way). **Hence an action is, essentially, a way of turning the elements of a group into transformations of a set.**

Are the terms "order" or "initial state" of relevance in this context? It might happen that they affect the situation, or that the way we define the action is related to the order, but what we are after is what the general case is: in general, **what we need** is a way to make the elements of $G$ into bijective maps $S \to S$, and have these form a group together, and nothing else.

Here's to be more precise.

When you talk about "order" of a set $S$ or when you want to talk about an "initial state", you can only make sense (algebraically speaking) by talking about a binary relation $\le \subset S \times S $ satisfying the $3$ axioms of an order. In this case, you have yourself a **pair** $(S,\le)$, and you are talking about this pair and not the set itself. We don't define group actions on such objects (extremely technically, the pair $(S,\le)$ is a set and we can define a group action, but that would be stretching it!). **We define group actions on raw sets**, and don't care about what kind of order they might be endowed with.

Comment: ok, so let's say that i have a group action with the group $\mathbb{Z} $ acting on $S = \{ A, B, C\}$ and that i map the element $1 \in \mathbb{Z}$ to a rotation to the right by 1 called $r^1$ because $r^1 \in Sym(S)$.

what does $1$ acting on $S$ do? it cant necesarily be $ 1.S = \{ C, A, B\}$ since there is no _default configuration_ in $S$ to tell me that the original configuration was $ A, B, C$ and therefore a rotation to the right would be $ C, A, B$ , that information is just not there on a set.

Comment: Please don't throw in the word "action" randomly. I won't take an example from you unless you can actually prove that your declared "action" is actually an "action" in the mathematical sense.

Comment: But just to note, in your example, what on earth is "rotation to the right" suppose to mean? Can you give me this map explicitly? The image of $S$ under this map is not well-defined because this map itself is not well-defined at all. The source of your problem is that your so-called symmetries are not even well-defined functions on the set.

Comment: mhh, ok, let me give it a try. given $Sym(S)$ where $|S|=3$, i define "rotation to the right" as being the element $r^1 \in Sym(S)$ defined as a cycle of length $3$ described as $\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & \\ 2 & 3 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}$  in  Cauchy's two-line notation.